# React Native move up image inside a view

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have an image inside a view, which is centered by default, so it cuts a bit of the top and bottom half, since the view is smaller than the image. 
But what I want is to just cut the top half, moving the image a bit up so it won't cut the bottom half.

Can't really explain but I hope you understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be helpful.

```
<View style={{width: 300, height: 300}}>
  <Image source={image} style={{position: 'absolute', bottom: 0}} />
</View>
```

Comment: As I said above, it kinda works, but image gets original size and won't fit the view. Even using width and height on container won't affect image.

Comment: just try, {{width: 200, height: 200, resizeMode: 'cover'}} on image

Comment: or resizeMode: 'contain'

Comment: I think I got it! Don't know how react native works, but I hope this works on all screen sizes since Im forcing width and height... Thank you :) @MR.OK

Comment: I think on that case, you should not use position absolute, also you can try width: null and height: null styles for automatically image sizing, but might not work well in all cases.

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
<View>
  <Image source={image} style={{bottom: 0}} />
</View>
```

Comment: not working. But with absolute position like below response kinda works, but image gets original size and won't fit the view.

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me

```
<View style={{width: 300, height: 300}}>
  <Image source={image} style={{position: 'absolute', top: 0}} />
</View>
```

Comment: Please add some description as to what your code does